# SQL Server query on multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-like

I have a SQL Server database with a *large* `products` table and a `category` table.

In the `product` table there is a `category` column which contains the ID of the corresponding category.
What I have to do is perform a LIKE query on both the product name column and the corresponding category name and return all the matching.

What kind of approach should I use considering I want to minimize the load on the server?

EDIT to improve this question:

*Results*:

product1 name->red apple catId->3    (cat_id = 3, "best apples")

product2 name->green apple catId->5  (cat_id = 5, "good fruits")

product3 name->green banana catId->8 (cat_id = 8, "apples & bananas")

Comment: easy. Just join the two tables and use the like option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, this will help you -

```
create table products(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,

[Name] NVARCHAR(MAX),
[CatId] INT
)

CREATE TABLE CATEGORIES(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
[Name] NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

insert into CATEGORIES values(1, 'Laptop')
insert into CATEGORIES values(2, 'Fruit')

insert into products values (2, 'Washington Apple', 2)
insert into products values (1, 'Apple mac book pro', 1)    

select * from products

SELECT p.[Name] as ProductName, c.[Name] as CategoryName FROM products p LEFT JOIN CATEGORIES c ON p.CatId = c.ID Where p.[Name] like '%apple%'
```

This code will join the two tables and return the products whose name matches the keyword and return their category names as well. You can modify the definition of products and categories to include other columns you want. You may also want to add FK constraint on catid.

Comment: This does what you described very well.
Thank you but what I was trying to achieve was different, but it's a good start I think.

Comment: I will improve my question